# Android percentage layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a layout that has two LinearLayout(vertcal position).

First linearLayout has 80% from space and the other 20% (I used weightSum=10).

On second layout I have a textinput and when keyboard appears the screen size is reduced so the second linearlayout wich has 20% is too small.

I would like that my secondLayout to have minimum 100dp and the first layout to have the rest but I don't know how to implement this.

Thank you !

[image: Print screen]

Comment: Using the support library, you can now use PercentRelativeLayout and PercentFrameLayout: https://juliengenoud.github.io/android-percent-support-lib-sample/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight is used to distribute the remaining empty space or take away space when the total sum is larger than the LinearLayout. Set your widths to 0dip instead and it will work.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum:"10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="8" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="0dip" 
        android:layout_weight="2">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is what I did but in this case the problem is that when orientation is landscape or when keyboard appears the second layout gets too small. I would like that my second layout to have 200dp height and the first layout to get the remaining space.

Comment: you can create Layout-land folder and create your xml in landscape.

Comment: That is true but when keyboard appears then what can I do ?

Comment: you add to the activity in AndroidManifest.xml
<activity
            android:name="com.Company.example.TestActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboard"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" />
        <activity

Comment: No this is not an option, it has to be a way to do this from the layout. For example text messaging application - how to they put at the bottom the text input and above they have the messages list. I don't think they use dpi

Comment: Try to use relative layout and set the linear layout contains the button to align parent bottom true and set the message list linear layout to be align above to message linear layout this solution will be fine